# Create a log normal distribution of random numbers?

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to re write some Python / numpy code in Fortran 90. In my Python code, I generate 5000 random log normal distributed numbers with the following command:

`numpy.random.lognormal(mu,sigma,5000)`

I'm trying to do the same thing in Fortran. I'm not very familiar with Fortran, but I found this on Intel's website:

`status = vdrnglognormal( method, stream, n, r, a, sigma, b, beta )`

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-C564D9DC-FDF0-426B-9C9D-1740969BDBEC.htm

I know what `n,r,a,sigma,b`, and `beta` are, but I have no idea what they mean by method / stream, and what I should pass those values as. Also, what is status? How would I call this function in my code? Do I need to include any files?

Comment: Do you have Intel's MKL installed ?

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution: the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) provides a function to return log normal deviates, gsl_ran_lognormal.  GSL is in C.  There is a Fortran interface, FGSL, http://www.lrz.de/services/software/mathematik/gsl/fortran/, using the ISO C Binding.  Or you can write your own interface.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can write your own log normal function.

Given a zero mean, unit deviation normally distributed random variable `x`, then a log normally distributed is simply

```
y = exp(mu+sigma*x)
```

And, if you don't have a function for `x` you can make one with just a few lines of code using the Marsaglia polar method.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to use the Marsaglia polar method? Thanks!